# Error: Call to function 'ExponentImagePicker.launchCameraAsync' has been rejected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to to make the user take a photo with "expo-image-picker" module using the "launchCameraAsync" function, and at first everything worked out fine, but now when trying to make the user take a photo, expo throws an warning and does not activate the camera, the warning is:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> Error: Call to function 'ExponentImagePicker.launchCameraAsync' has been rejected.
> → Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()

The code section responsible for this error is:

```
const permission = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
if (permission.granted === false)
  //Error handeling

console.log(permission);
let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
  base64: false,
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [3, 2],
  quality: 1,
});
console.log(result);
if (!result.cancelled) {
  console.log(result.uri);
  setImages({ ...images, document: result.uri });
}
```

I believe the error may be due to incompatibility with other expo modules but I'm not sure because I have not updated or changed the modules in my app, either way here are the versions of what I believe are the relevant modules.

```
"expo": "~46.0.16",
"expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
"expo-updates": "~0.14.6",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also face the same problem just yesterday. and everything solve when I clear the memory of the app. you can try if its work for you too

Comment: Could you please share which steps you took for you clearing the memory?

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21544#issuecomment-1642011901

I have a Samsung S20 FE with Android 13 and expo go 2.29.5

```
config :
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4"
```

example:

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
    
  [photo, setPhoto] = useState(null);
    
  const onClick = async () => {
    const cameraPermission = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (cameraPermission.granted === false) {
      return;
    }

    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: false,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      const { assets } = result;
      if (assets && assets.length > 0) {
        setPhoto(assets[0].uri);
      }
    }
  };
```